# Looping through the ResultSet efficiently and the add the values for columns in List<String>

Tags: java, optimization, multithreading

I am working on a multithreaded project in which each thread will `randomly find columns for that table` and I will be using those columns in my `SELECT sql query` and then I will be executing that SELECT sql query. AFter exectuing that query, I will be looping through the result set and will add the data for each columns into `List<String>`.

Here `columnsList` will contains `columns` delimited by `comma`. For example-

`col1, col2, col3`

Below is my code.

```
class ReadTask implements Runnable {

public ReadTask() {

}


@Override
public run() {
  ...

  while ( < 60 minutes) {

    .....

    final int id = generateRandomId(random);
    final String columnsList = getColumns(table.getColumns());
    final String selectSql = "SELECT " + columnsList + "  from " + table.getTableName() + " where id = ?";
    resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    List<String> colData = new ArrayList<String>(columnsList.split(",").length);
    boolean foundData = false;

    if (id >= startValidRange && id <= endValidRange) {

        if (resultSet.next()) {
            foundData = true;
            for (String column : columnsList.split(",")) {
                colData.add(resultSet.getString(column.trim()));
            }
            resultSet.next();//do I need this here?
        }
    } else if (resultSet.next()) {
        addException("Data Present for Non Valid ID's", Read.flagTerminate);
    }

    ....
      }
   }


    private static void addException(String cause, boolean flagTerminate) {
        AtomicInteger count = exceptionMap.get(cause);
        if (count == null) {
            count = new AtomicInteger();
            AtomicInteger curCount = exceptionMap.putIfAbsent(cause, count);
            if (curCount != null) {
                count = curCount;
            }
        }
        count.incrementAndGet();

        if(flagTerminate) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

After executing the `SELECT` sql query. Below are my two scenarios-

1. I need to see whether the id is between the valid range. If it is between the Valid Range then check whether `resultSet` has any data or not. If it has data then loop around the `resultSet` using the `columns` from the `columnsList` and start adding it in `coldData` list of String.
2. else if id is not in the valid range then I need to check I am not getting any data back from the `resultSet`. But somehow if I am getting the data back and flag is true to stop the program, then exit the program. Else if I am getting the data back but flag is false to stop the program, then count how many of those happening. So for this, I have created `addException` method.

Can anyone help me out whether the way I am doing here for my above two `scenarios` is right or not? It looks like, I can improve the `if/else loop` code more I guess for my above two scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not that familiar with JDBC, but I think the method you search for is: [isBeforeFirst](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#isBeforeFirst%28%29): "true if the cursor is before the first row; false if the cursor is at any other position or the result set contains no rows"

This does not modify the results cursor then.

---

```
if (id >= startValidRange && id <= endValidRange)
```

I would change it to:

```
if (startValidRange <= id && id <= endValidRange)
```

Only a small change, but increase readability a lot (at least for me)